# CSS Floats, How to move boxs underneath one another?

Tags: html, css

I"m having a big of trouble. Im trying to create a game but running into a floating element problem. The blue box is the players avatar, the red boxs will be hp and other stats, and the white box is a chat area of whats going on in the game. The problem i'm having is with the first 3 red boxs that are floating to the left. I want them to float underneath one another so it looks like a vertical column instead of a horiztonal column, but the only way to do that is to get the floated box to touch the edge of my container box. Is there a way to say to it, that the white box is kind of like the edge and it should move down 1 spot so it will create a vertical column? Thanks.

**CSS**

```css
#mainbody {
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #665544;
  background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
  height: 850px;
  width: 960px;
}
#topbody {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
  height: 400px;
  width: 960px;
}
#chatbox {
  border: 1px solid #665544;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#usercontainer {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#userimage {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#userHP {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  clear: right;
}
#userMANA {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  clear: right;
}
#userENERGY {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#enemycontainer {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px 20px 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#enemyimage {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#enemyHP {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#enemyMANA {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#enemyENERGY {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <link href="css/game.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <div id="mainbody">
      <div id="topbody">
        <div id="usercontainer">
          <div id="userimage">
          </div>
          <!--END OF USER IMAGE-->
        </div>
        <!--END OF USER CONTAINER-->
        <div id="userHP">
        </div>
        <div id="userMANA">
        </div>
        <div id="userENERGY">
        </div>
        <div id="chatbox">
        </div>
        <!--END OF CHAT BOX-->
        <div id="enemyHP">
        </div>
        <div id="enemyMANA">
        </div>
        <div id="enemyENERGY">
        </div>
        <div id="enemycontainer">
          <div id="enemyimage">
          </div>
          <!--END OF ENEMY IMAGE-->
        </div>
        <!--END OF ENEMY CONTAINER-->
      </div>
      <!--END OF TOP BODY-->
    </div>
    <!--END OF MAIN BODY-->
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why are you floating them if you want them to stack vertically? It would be much easier to have them as block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap three red boxes inside a float wrapper, try this:

```css
#mainbody {
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid #665544;
        background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);
        height: 850px;
        width: 960px;
    }

    #topbody {
        float: left;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
        height: 400px;
        width: 960px;
    }

    #chatbox {
        border: 1px solid #665544;
        float: left;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #usercontainer {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #userimage {
        background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #userHP {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
        clear: right;
    }

    #userMANA {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
        clear: right;
    }

    #userENERGY {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    #enemycontainer {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 20px 20px 10px 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #enemyimage {
        background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #enemyHP {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    #enemyMANA {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    #enemyENERGY {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: rgb(200, 20, 50);
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 65px;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div id="mainbody">
    <div id="topbody">

        <div id="usercontainer">
            <div id="userimage">
            </div>
            <!--END OF USER IMAGE-->
        </div>
        <!--END OF USER CONTAINER-->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="userHP">
            </div>
            <div id="userMANA">
            </div>
            <div id="userENERGY">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chatbox">
        </div>
        <!--END OF CHAT BOX-->

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="enemyHP">
            </div>
            <div id="enemyMANA">
            </div>
            <div id="enemyENERGY">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="enemycontainer">
            <div id="enemyimage">
            </div>
            <!--END OF ENEMY IMAGE-->
        </div>
        <!--END OF ENEMY CONTAINER-->
</div>
</div>
```